# Swagger Codegen basePath is being ignored

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-codegen, contract-first

I'm trying to generate some web services definitions using **Swagger Codegen » 2.2.1**

All configs are working and the classes are generate correctly by my `.yaml` definitions.

> #### Why the property **`basePath`** is being ignored?

---

My `@RestController` generate using only `paths` definition:

```
https://springboot-base-save-return.appdes.xnet/saveBackendReturn
```

Expected (using `basePath` and `paths` definitions):

```
https://springboot-base-save-return.appdes.xnet/v1/saveBackendReturn
```

What am I doing wrong? Did I forget something?

---

My `.yaml` contract:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  description: My Project
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Save Backend Return
host: springboot-base-save-return.appdes.xnet
basePath: /v1
tags:
  - name: saveBackendReturn
    description: Save Backend Return
schemes:
  - https
paths:
  /saveBackendReturn:
    post:
      tags:
        - saveBackendReturn
      summary: Save Backend Return
      description: My Project
      operationId: saveBackendReturn
      consumes:
        - application/json
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: body
          description: My Project
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/saveBackendReturnRequest'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Ok
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/saveBackendReturnResponse'
        '400':
          description: Bad Request
        '401':
          description: Unauthorized
        '500':
          description: Internal Server Error
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
      security:
        - basicAuth: []
```

Comment: 2.2.1 is a very old version, please try 2.4.12.

Comment: @Helen Thanks for your comment, it was assertive to resolve the problem.

Comment: I don't think the issue has been fixed when using the `html` "codegen".  The generated docs still don't mention the basePath.

I'm on v3.0.20

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Searching more about this, I found the [**issue**](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/5244).

It's a bug fixed by [HugoMario](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/commits?author=HugoMario) (*[commit](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/commit/f1569a03092ba28f52c69053e107acd5f01f0467) referenced on 2 Dec 2019*)

- [[Spring] Fixes #5244 Include basePath @RequestMapping in Spring API template](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/pull/8131)
- Release on [master (#8131)](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/pull/8131/commits/ff11895e80f29f548621448d0fcd3482a7c4ed1e) »  [v2.4.12](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/releases/tag/v2.4.12) / [v2.4.11](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/releases/tag/v2.4.11)

#### And following [Helen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113116/helen) suggestion, I update my Swagger Codegen:

- From » [2.2.1](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/releases/tag/v2.2.1) »  old release (*Aug 07, 2016*)
- To   » [**2.4.12**](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/releases/tag/v2.4.12) » **current stable release** (*Jan 15, 2020*)

> **Summary:**
> » It's a **bug** of an **outdated version**
> » *Now works fine!*

---

Maven dependecy for **`swagger-codegen-maven-plugin`**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.12</version>
</dependency>
```

**Maven Central Repository** (*check new releases*):

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

---

**Update Maven Project** (*Eclipse shortcut **`F5`***) and make a **clean build**:

```
mvn clean verify 
mvn install
```

---

#### Reference:

- https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen