# swagger-codegen : Problem of add "default" to generated Path => @Path("/default)

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, swagger-codegen

Problem :

in api.json :

"paths": {
"/": {

In generated source :

@path("/default")

---

Wanted :

in api.json :

"paths": {
"/": {

In generated source :

@path("/")

---

language : lang-jersey

swagger-codegen-maven-plugin-2.2.1

Comment: Do you have `basePath` in your OpenAPI file?

Comment: yes i had it with "/" and it gives same result with or without basePath

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59918115/swagger-codegen-basepath-is-being-ignored